# Variable Substitution in C

Tags: c, variables, substitution

I want to open a file. Easy enough. Use fopen(). However, what file to open depends on the user input. I am somewhat proficient in Korn Shell scripting and this is easily done using variable substitution: $(var). I am unable to figure out the correct format in C. Could someone please give me some insight?
My code -

```
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <stdio.h>

 char statsA[100];
 char fileA[50];

 int main (void)
 {

 printf("Enter file to open\n");
 gets(fileA);


 FILE *statsA;
 statsA = fopen("c:/Users/SeanA/C/***<fileA>***", "r+");

 .......................................^ What goes here?
```

I am unsure of how to include the user input in the fopen string.

Comment: Try looking into the `sprintf` function.

Comment: Or even better, [`snprintf`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/snprintf).

Comment: Obligatory: do not use `gets`, because with it user can *always* crash your program, and it also has been removed from current standard C (just because of this).

Comment: You need to build a new string that combines the path and the filename using one of the methods mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

This is what `sprintf` is for.  It works like `printf`, except that its output goes to a string instead of `stdout`.

```
char filename[100];
sprintf(filename, "c:/Users/SeanA/C/%s", fileA);
statsA = fopen(filename, "r+");
```

Also, the definition of `statsA` you have inside of `main` masks the definition at file scope.  You probably want to give these different names.

Answer (score 0):

Do `scanf` to get the file from the user.

make a char array to hold the filename.

`char filename[15];`

Now ask for the file name:

`printf("What is the name of the file?\n");`

`scanf("%s", &filename);`

Note: Include the FULL file name. so if I have a text doc called `filename` The user would need to type `filename.txt`

Now you have the file name you can declare a file pointer

`FILE * fp;`

`fp = fopen(filename, "r");`

Now you should be able to scan your file!

`fscanf(fp, "%d", &value);`

**EDIT:** I did not notice you wanted string concatenation with your file path.

Since you know the predefined path you can make another char array that holds that string path

`char fullPath[100];`

`char path[75] = "c:/Users/SeanA/C/";`

Now you can use `strcat` to bring them all together!

`strcat(fullPath, path);`

`strcat(fullPath, filename);`

Now you do `fopen(fullPath, "r");`

Comment: Note that your `scanf` will fail if file name contains spaces... and also has the exact same buffer overflow problem as gets.

Comment: Anyway, the question is about how to do string concatenation in C, and your answer doesn't seem to answer that.

Comment: Indeed, but for his purposes he may not be worried about that too much. I guess in the scanf file name, we can put that in an if statement, seeing if it's equal to 1 or not. If not, then we error out.

Comment: @hyde ah I didn't notice that! give me a second I shall fix that.

Comment: @hyde Is that better?

Comment: Well, it answers the question now... (the downvote isn't mine btw, in case you're thinking about that).

Comment: @hyde No worries about that, don't really care about it honestly. Just wanted a confirmed second opinion. Thanks mate.

Answer (score 0):

You must concatenate both strings manually. Something like this

```
char* folder = "c:/Users/SeanA/C/";
char* path = malloc(strlen(fileA) + strlen(folder) + 1);
path = strcpy(folder);
path = strcat(fileA);

FILE *statsA = fopen(path, "r+");

free(path);//Always free your memory
```