# Variable substitution in C (in the variable name itself)

Tags: c

I am trying to use variable substitution in C. Basically i am trying to 
find the shortest path b/w source and destination node in a graph. Here i have considered 5 nodes A, B, C, D and E. I have stored the distances of the nodes in dist_a, dist_b etc. arrays (I could have stored the distances in 5x5 matrix too.). In the for loop, i am checking for the immediate neighbours of the destination node (which is an input from user). But how do i substitute that value from the **dstn** variable so that condition becomes like **dist_e** (if user inputs e as destination)?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

void main()
{
int i,j;
char src, dstn, c;

int dist_a[5]={0,1,6,5,1000}; //taking 1000 as infinity means nodes aren't connected directly to each other
int dist_b[5]={1,0,1000,1,1000};
int dist_c[5]={6,1000,0,1,1};
int dist_d[5]={5,1,1,0,2};
int dist_e[5]={1000,1000,1,2,0};
clrscr();

printf("Enter source and destination\n");
scanf("%c %c",&src,&dstn);
printf("src = %c destn = %c",src,dstn);

for(i=0;i<=4;i++)
 {
   if(dist_dstn[i]!=0 && dist_dstn[i]!=1000)  //The PROBLEM lies here. How do i substitute the value of dstn variable in the condition part.
     {printf("%c updates to %d",dstn,i);}
 }

getch();
}
```

I have seen [Variable Substitution in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36800518/variable-substitution-in-c) but i think that it isn't applicable here.

Comment: you don't. That's not how variables work in C

Comment: Variable name does not even exist after compilation...

Comment: You should consider updating to a compiler which isn't 28 years old/ancient.

Comment: @Lundin :) Yes, you are right. I use new compiler on my own laptop but in the college labs, i can't do anything !

Comment: You could always shame your school publicly on the internet for being bad at teaching programming...

Answer (score 4):

C is not a *reflective* language in the sense that variable names can be inspected at runtime.

But in your case, why don't you use a 2D array:

```
int dist[][5]={ 
    {0,1,6,5,1000},
    {1,0,1000,1,1000},
    {6,1000,0,1,1},
    {5,1,1,0,2},
    {1000,1000,1,2,0}
};
```

You can then pick out the strip you need with appropriate indexing of this array. Map `a` to 0, `b` to 1, etc. A `switch` block would suffice. (Don't assume ASCII with flashy `c - 'a'` type idioms for a char `c`.)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you have created 5 individual, non-related arrays. Don't do that.

Instead you can define a custom type:

```
typedef struct
{
  int distance [5];
} dist_t;
```

Then declare an array of such types:

```
dist_t dist [5] = 
{
  {0,1,6,5,1000},
  {1,0,1000,1,1000},
  ...
};
```

And then iterate over that array.